# Generating verilog file for rocket chip

Tags: chisel, rocket-chip

I am a beginner working with rocket chip generator for my project but I am not able to generate the verilog file for it and facing this error. I am using an apple M1 chip macOS. I started with cloning the repository, installing the rocket tools for Mac (https://github.com/riscv-software-src/homebrew-riscv), jdk 17.0.10, sbt 1.9.9, Mill 0.11.7 and tried to generate the verilog. Are there some other steps involved?

```
srishtisharma@Srishtis-MacBook-Pro ~ % cd rocket-chip
srishtisharma@Srishtis-MacBook-Pro rocket-chip % make verilog
cd /Users/srishtisharma/rocket-chip && mill emulator[freechips.rocketchip.system.TestHarness,freechips.rocketchip.system.DefaultConfig].mfccompiler.compile
[172/172] emulator[freechips.rocketchip.system.TestHarness,freechips.rocketchip.system.DefaultConfig].mfccompiler.compile 
1 targets failed
emulator[freechips.rocketchip.system.TestHarness,freechips.rocketchip.system.DefaultConfig].mfccompiler.compile java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "firtool" (in directory "/Users/srishtisharma/rocket-chip/out/emulator/freechips.rocketchip.system.TestHarness/freechips.rocketchip.system.DefaultConfig/mfccompiler/compile.dest"): error=2, No such file or directory
    java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1170)
    java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1089)
    os.proc.proc$lzycompute$1(ProcessOps.scala:123)
    os.proc.proc$1(ProcessOps.scala:122)
    os.proc.spawn(ProcessOps.scala:129)
    os.proc.call(ProcessOps.scala:87)
    millbuild.build$Emulator$mfccompiler$.$anonfun$compile$3(build.sc:151)
java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:295)
    java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:225)
    java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1126)
    java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1089)
    os.proc.proc$lzycompute$1(ProcessOps.scala:123)
    os.proc.proc$1(ProcessOps.scala:122)
    os.proc.spawn(ProcessOps.scala:129)
    os.proc.call(ProcessOps.scala:87)
    millbuild.build$Emulator$mfccompiler$.$anonfun$compile$3(build.sc:151)
make: *** [verilog] Error 1
srishtisharma@Srishtis-MacBook-Pro rocket-chip %
```

Comment: Yes, another step is to ensure that the program "firtool" can be found and run.

Comment: how to ensure that @mkrieger

Comment: I don't know exactly, you probably have to at least install it or install some package that includes it.